# Difference between "@" and "$" in Perl

Tags: perl

What are the differences between `@variable` and `$variable` in Perl?

I have read code with the symbol `$` and the symbol `@` before a variable name.

For example:

```
$info = "Caine:Michael:Actor:14, Leafy Drive";
@personal = split(/:/, $info);
```

What are the difference between a variable containing `$` as opposed to `@`?

Comment: `$`- scalar, `@` - array. `$info` is a scalar string containing `:`, @personal - array to wich the return value of split function is assigned. `split` takes two argument (delimiter, valueToSplit)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731542/what-is-the-difference-between-this-that-and-those-in-perl

Comment: There is a very good and concise description in **[perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types)**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your knowledge about **Perl** will be crashed with mountains, when you don't *feel* context of this language.

As many people, you use in your speech single value (scalars) and many things in a set.

So, the difference between all of them:

i have a cat.    `$myCatName = 'Snowball';`

it jump on bed where sit `@allFriends = qw(Fred John David);`

And you can count them `$count = @allFriends;`

but can't count them at all cause list of names not countable: `$nameNotCount = (Fred John David);`

So, after all:

```
print $myCatName = 'Snowball';           # scalar
print @allFriends = qw(Fred John David); # array! (countable)
print $count = @allFriends;              # count of elements (cause array)
print $nameNotCount = qw(Fred John David); # last element of list (uncountable)
```

So, **list** is not the same, as an **array**.

Interesting feature is slices where your mind will play a trick with you:

this code is a magic:

```
my @allFriends = qw(Fred John David);
$anotherFriendComeToParty =qq(Chris);
$allFriends[@allFriends] = $anotherFriendComeToParty; # normal, add to the end of my friends
say  @allFriends;
@allFriends[@allFriends] = $anotherFriendComeToParty; # WHAT?! WAIT?! WHAT HAPPEN? 
say  @allFriends;
```

so, after all things:

**Perl** have an interesting feature about context. your `$` and `@` are sigils, that help **Perl** know, what you *want*, not what you *really mean*.

`$` like `s`, so scalar
`@` like `a`, so array

Answer (score 7):

It isn't really about the *variable*, but more about the *context* how the variable is used. If you put a `$` in front of the variable name, then it is used in scalar context, if you have a `@` that means you use the variable in list context.

- `my @arr;` defines variable `arr` as array
- when you want to access one individual element (that is a scalar context), you have to use `$arr[0]`

You can find more about Perl contexts here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558

Comment: Good answer. You can also think of `$` as `This` (*This number is 42* <=> `$number = 42`) and of `@` as `These` (*These values are (1 .. 42)* <=> `@values = (1 .. 42)` and *This last value* <=> `$values[-1]`)

Comment: `@arr` is **array**, not **list**. see behavior: `print $s = @all = qw(my list here);` and `print $s = qw(my list here);`

Comment: i want to hear about list and scalar contexes of single-slices, please. 
does here `@one[$one]` `@` means list context? it is not true in all situations

Answer (score 4):

Variables that start $ are scalars, a single value.

```
   $name = "david";
```

Variables that start @ are arrays:

```
   @names = ("dracula", "frankenstein", "dave");
```

If you refer to a single value from the array, you use the $

```
   print "$names[1]"; // will print frankenstein
```

Answer (score 3):

From [`perldoc perlfaq7`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What-are-all-these-%24%40%25%26%2a-punctuation-signs%2c-and-how-do-I-know-when-to-use-them%3f)

> **What are all these $@%&* punctuation signs, and how do I know when to use them?**
>
> They are type specifiers, as detailed in
>   [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):
>
> ```
> $ for scalar values (number, string or reference)
> @ for arrays
> % for hashes (associative arrays)
> & for subroutines (aka functions, procedures, methods)
> * for all types of that symbol name. In version 4 you used them like
>   pointers, but in modern perls you can just use references.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is for scalar variables(in your case a string variable.)
`@` is for arrays.

`split` function will split the variable passed to it acoording to the delimiter mentioned(`:`) and put the strings in the array.

Comment: Pedantically, the `split` function turns the scalar into a *list*. The assignment then stores that list in an array.

Comment: $n is a scalar(here an index of an array) and $array[$n] will be another scalar variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Variable name starts with $ symbol called scalar variable.
Variable name starts with @ symbol called array.

$var -> can hold single value.
@var -> can hold bunch of values ie., it contains list of scalar values.
```