# why pop/shift not work with map/grep in perl

Tags: perl

I want to get first or last element after `map` and `grep` operations
over array. Using `shift` and `pop` operators with `map` and `grep` 
does not seem to work. Any suggestions? It works if I save result from `map`
into array variable and do pop on that but I want to do that in one line.

```
:$ cat map.pl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
my $ele = pop ( map{10* $_ } @arr ) ;
print "\n element is $ele";
:$ perl map.pl
Not an ARRAY reference at map.pl line 4.
```

Comment: In list context, `map` and `grep` produce lists, but `shift`/`unshift` and `push`/`pop` operate on arrays. Lists and arrays are not the same thing in Perl. You should be less worried about trying to do everything in one line, and more worried about writing code that's correct.

Comment: @MattJacob I thought that was a good answer to the question

Comment: A good link from a (good but deleted?) answer by Matt Jacob: [list vs array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001741/what-is-the-difference-between-lists-and-arrays)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
map{10* $_ } @arr
```

produces a list whose elements are corresponding elements of `@arr` multiplied by `10`. It **does not** produce an array. Therefore, you cannot `pop` anything out of it. You can access the last element though:

```
(map 10 * $_, @arr)[-1]
```

However, the map does not change `@arr`. If you want to do that,

```
 $_ *= 10 for @arr;
```

is more appropriate than `map`.

Answer (score 7):

The first argument to `shift` and `pop` must be an array (`@NAME` or `@BLOCK`), not a `map` or `grep` operator (which have nothing to do with arrays).

You could build an array from which to `shift`/`pop`.

```
my $first_ele = shift @{ [ map { 10 * $_ } @arr ] };           # If you want first
my $last_ele  = pop   @{ [ map { 10 * $_ } @arr ] };           # If you want last
```

But that's very wasteful. You could avoid the array creation by using a list assignment or a list slice.

```
my ($first_ele) = map { 10 * $_ } @arr;                        # If you want first
my $first_ele = ( map { 10 * $_ } @arr )[0];                   # If you want first
my $last_ele  = ( map { 10 * $_ } @arr )[-1];                  # If you want last
my ($first_ele, $last_ele) = ( map { 10 * $_ } @arr )[0, -1];  # If you want both
```

But that's still wasteful. There's no need to multiply all the elements when you only want the product of last one. The following makes far more sense:

```
my $first_ele = 10 * $arr[0];                                  # If you want first
my $last_ele  = 10 * $arr[-1];                                 # If you want last
my ($first_ele, $last_ele) = map { 10 * $_ } @arr[0, -1];      # If you want both
```

Answer (score 3):

In list context, `map` and `grep` produce lists, but `shift`/`unshift` and `push`/`pop` operate on arrays. [Lists and arrays are not the same thing in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001741/what-is-the-difference-between-lists-and-arrays). You should be less worried about trying to do everything in one line, and more worried about writing code that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

First or last? For first you can use

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    my @arr = (1,2,3,4);
    my ($ele) = map{10* $_ } @arr;
    print "\n element is $ele\n\n";
```

Comment: Seems the OP wants to be able to do both as they mention both first and last, and shift and pop. I adjusted the OP to make that clear.