# How can I get the nth element of a dereferenced anonymous array?

Tags: perl

```
use strict;

my $anon = [1,3,5,7,9];
my $aref  = [\$anon];

print "3rd element: "  . $ { $aref } [2] . "\n";
```

I'd like to get the nth element of the anonymous array `$anon` over the `$aref` variable. In the code I wanted to get the 3rd element of `$anon` by making the index 2 but it returned nothing. If I write  `$ { $aref } [0]` then it returns something like REF(0x7fd459027ac0)

How can I get the nth, for example the 3rd element of `$anon` ?

Rationale:

```
my @area = (
    qw[1 3 5 7 9],
    qw[2 4 6 8 0],
    qw[a e i u o],
    qw[b c d f g]
    );

foreach my $row (@area) {
    foreach my $cell (@$row)
    {
    # do some processing on the element
    print $cell . " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: *"the nth element of the anonymous array `$anon` over the `$aref` variable"* What does *"over the `$aref` variable"* mean?

Comment: *"I wanted to get the 3rd element of $anon by making the index 2 but it returned nothing"* No subroutine can return *nothing* and no variable can contain *nothing*. What do you mean here?

Comment: `[ LIST ]` is basically short for `do { my @a = LIST; \@a }`, so you have `my @x = (1,3,5,7,9); my $anon = \@anon; my $y = \$anon; my @z = ($y); my $aref = \@z;` and you would need `${ ${ ${ $aref }[0] } }[2]` or `$aref->[0]->$*->[2]` for that wacky data structure. Of course, you should be using `my @array  = (1,3,5,7,9); my $anon = \@array;` with `$ { $aref } [2]` or `$aref->[2]`.

Comment: @Borodin What does "over the $aref variable" mean? Sorry for the late reply (I had to go bed after I posted the question) I mean iterating over the `$anon` using another variable such as `$aref` so that I can loop over and process the elements of `$anon`

Comment: @Borodin No subroutine can return nothing and no variable can contain nothing. What do you mean here? I meant space. On the console output, it returned without any error but because it didn't output any element I called it simply nothing.

Comment: The way you changed the code now invalidates the answers. What you have there now is just an array. `qw()` returns a list of quoted words. The fact that you chose `[` as the delimiter doesn't make that list an array reference. Your `@area` will just be a flat array with elements `1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 'a', 'e', ...`.

Comment: @simbabque How to make the words returned by `qw( )` arrays and/or array references so that I can access for instance `1, 3, 5, 7, 9` , `2, 4, 6, 8, 0` separately? How to avoid making a flat array meanwhile?

Comment: `my @foo = ( [ qw/a b c/ ], [ qw/1 2 3/ ], ... )` – you should really read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: @simbabque Actually I read Programming Perl 4th edition, particularly the 8th chapter called 'References'. That part which you added square brackets to `qw/a b c/` expressions  seems to solve the problem. The 8th chapter of the book and the perlreftut just didn't give information on that particular case, i.e. how to make `qw( )` block a distinct array.

Comment: `qw()` is not a block. In programming, the right terminology is very important, so we know what we're talking about. `qw()` returns a _list_. And a list is not an array either in Perl. Essentially you can assign the list to an array variable, and you can stick a list into an anonymous array reference, but you cannot take the reference of a list. Give it some practice and you'll quickly get the hang of this. Knowing when to use `[]`, `{}` or neither and how to stick those into each other will come naturally after a while. :)

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14006130/1331451 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6024268/1331451 and https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/01/whats-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array/.

Comment: @simbabque I took a look at the links; they're so helpful. so it seems I basically got stuck trying to take a reference of the list returned by `qw( )` The trick is to enclose `qw` in brackets (in par with your previous comment) and I couldn't find it though I browsed various posts, articles, tutorials.

Comment: Well the point is, you cannot take a reference of a list. You stick a list into an anonymous array reference. The list is just several pieces of information together, while an array is giving them a name, and a reference to an array is turning that array into a scalar pointer-like thing that you can pass around without copying all the values in the array all the time.

Comment: It would help if we knew what you were trying to do with the data. Looking at the data structure you provided, it reminds me a lot of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) where you use two arrays to loop through the rows and columns of a spreadsheet to determine the coordinates of each cell. Take a look at the synopsis of the module and see if it's close to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I get the nth element of a dereferenced anonymous array?

You have too many *reference to* operators. You have built a nested structure three levels deep and it's no wonder you're having trouble navigating it

The problem is that your `$anon` is already a *reference to an anonymous array*. Square brackets `[...]` construct an anonymous array and return a reference to it

You then have

```
my $aref  = [\$anon]
```

which creates another reference to an array with one element: a reference to the *scalar* `$anon`.

So you have built this

```
$anon = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

$aref = [ \ [1, 3, 5, 7, 9] ]
```

So

```
${$aref}[0]          is \ [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
${${$aref}[0]}       is [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
${${${$aref}[0]}}[2] is 5
```

But why are you working with references to arrays at all, and especially references to scalars? It would be best to begin with an ordinary array, and write

```
my @array = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 );
my $aref = \@array;

print $aref->[2];
```

#### output

```
5
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the rationale. I'd like to iterate over the array elements of an array inside a loop so that I can process them. I have to use `qw` to make it look simple and readable, but when I use `qw`, it looks like the array becomes anonymous. I'd like to iterate over those anonymous arrays and their elements.

Answer (score 1):

You have a classic list-of-lists data structure, with a twist. You need to fetch the first element of the outer array reference, given by `$aref`, dereference the result, and then fetch the *n*th element of the inner array reference returned by that expression. This should do the trick:

```
${ $aref->[0] }->[2]
```

You may want to read through [perllol](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) and possibly even [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information and ideas. If you have control over this data structure, there are better ways to build it. For example, if it were built like so:

```
my $anon = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]; # a reference to an anonymous array
my $aref = [$anon]; # a reference to an anonymous array containing only the above reference
```

You could simply do:

```
$aref->[0][2]
```

Comment: Please check your code before posting. `$aref->[0]` is the *scalar* `\$anon` and won't take kindly to being indexed. Your suggestion will cause a ***Not an ARRAY reference*** warning. You should think twice if the answer to a question seems obvious.

Comment: Ah, I missed the double reference. Thanks @Borodin. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the rationale behind my question. I'd like to iterate over the array elements of an array inside a loop so that I can process them. I have to use `qw` to make the arrays look simple and readable, but when I use `qw`, it looks like the array becomes anonymous. That's why I tried to get the nth element of those anonymous arrays using a dereference operator.

Comment: @Romario In your updated example, you actually end up with a one-dimensional, flattened array. I suggest you use something like Data::Dumper to inspect your data structures to see what's actually happening. `use Data::Dumper; die Dumper(\@area);` My advice about reading perllol stands!

Comment: @mwp Yes it's kind of a one-dimensional array and I just can't do any proper iteration yet operation on it.  I've tried making it like http://oi65.tinypic.com/307qnox.jpg (screenshot) but still got difficulties iterating. I had added Data::Dumper but couldn't get any useful information of it so I gave up using it.