# What does the 'Array => [...]' notation mean

Tags: arrays, perl

In some Perl code I have been asked to maintain, I encountered the following construct:

```
myArray => ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
```

I searched the web for some definition/explanation of this but all I could find was a reference to scalar hashing:

https://www.guru99.com/perl-tutorials.html

This is a snippet from the actual code I encountered:

```
$config = eval {
    XMLin(
        $inFile,
        MyArray => [
            'id1', 'id2',"id3", 'id4'
        ]
    );
};
```

What does that syntax of hashing an entire array (without the hash values) mean?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093895/how-does-double-arrow-operator-work-in-perl but welcome to SO

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn Thank you. I will check that link that you provided (I did search SO before I posted but couldn't find it). Maybe this is not an exact duplicate because I was referring to this confusing array declaration onlly.

Comment: The `[ ]` brackets create an array ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155543/14955

Comment: What do you mean by "hashing an entire array without the hash values"? The array is the value.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid XML::Simple. Despite its name, [it's so complicated to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33267765/589924) that its own documentation recommends avoiding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention hashing and hashes, but neither are involved.

---

```
IDENT => ...
```

is the same as

```
'IDENT', ...
```

---

```
[ ... ]
```

is basically equivalent to

```
do { my @anon = ( ... ); \@anon }
```

except without the new scope.

---

```
XMLin(
    $inFile,
    MyArray => [
        'id1', 'id2',"id3", 'id4'
    ]
);
```

is equivalent to

```
my @anon = ( 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4' );
XMLin($inFile, 'MyArray', \@anon);
```

This isn't a proper call to `XMLin`. If present, the second argument should be the name of one of the options (e.g. `ForceArray`.)